# Allow <canvas> tags in TinyMCE

Tags: html, tinymce, html5-canvas

I have an existing site (I didn't build it) that uses tinyMCE. I'm trying to avoid having to rip it out and go with something else, so I figured I'd try and see if anyone has done this before.

Overview:

The page in the app is to edit questions for a quiz/assignment. 99% of the questions are pretty standard stuff: textboxes, textareas, etc. However, the left over stuff, needs to have canvas. A nifty little graphing utility was written for these assignments, but whenever there is something with a `<canvas>` tag, we need to edit the data in the database manually.

The Question:

Is there a way to tell TinyMCE to allow the `<canvas>` tag to just be there when saving and NOT be removed? I don't necessarily want TinyMCE to do anything to the tag, I just want it left there so we don't have to edit the database every time someone wants one the values changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done using the tinymce configuration.
Check out the settings [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) and [valid_children](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_children).
you will need to add `canvas` to the valid_elemnts and define valid children using the `valid_children` setting.